# How to Show Custom Dialog on OnBackPressed

Tags: java, android

I want to show a custom dialog box whenever someone clicks on the back button on the main Activity to exit the app.

I tried multiple methods but non worked for me. I simply want to have 4 icons (buttons) and a text line in that dialog box along with "exit" the app option.

Is there any workable solution you guys can suggest??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an action when user clicks the back button you can simplly override the `onBackPressed()` , to show a custom dialog you need to do 2 things, first create the layout of the dialog with the 4 buttons and the text you want.

custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#3E80B4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Your text goes here"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#3E80B4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_no"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="No"
            android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then Create a custom dialog class exteding `Dialog` and implements `OnClickListener`

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public CustomDialogListener listener;
    public Dialog d;
    public Button yes, no, exit;

    public CustomDialogClass(@NonNull Context context,
                             CustomDialogListener listener) {
        super(context);
        this.listener = listener ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
        no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_exit);
        yes.setOnClickListener(this);
        no.setOnClickListener(this);
        exit.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_yes:
                listener.onYesButtonClicked();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_no:
                listener.onNoButtonClicked();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_exit:
                listener.onExitButtonClicked();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }

    public interface CustomDialogListener {
        public void onYesButtonClicked() ;
        public void onNoButtonClicked() ;
        public void onExitButtonClicked() ;
    }

}
```

Finally at the MainActivity class ovverride the `onBackPressed()` , show the dialog and handle all button clicks

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        CustomDialogClass cd = new CustomDialogClass(this, new CustomDialogClass.CustomDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onYesButtonClicked() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yes Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNoButtonClicked() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onExitButtonClicked() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exit Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        cd.show();
    }
```

Comment: do I have to create a new activity for CustomDialogClass? because I want to implement this in the main activity where it already says public class MainActivity
        extends Activity

        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, PowerfulActionModeSupport

Comment: No you don't need to create a new activity, All you need is to create the CustomDialogClass which is a **Class** not an activity and then override the onBackPressed() method in the MainActivity

Comment: It worked Brother :) Thankyou so much for your help

Comment: Happy to hear that :D , you can accept this answer as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to override your main activitys `onBackPressed()` function. If users press the back button, it will be triggered. Then you can pop-up your custom dialog and if the exit button is clicked on your dialog you can call `super.onBackPressed()` or `finish()`. This will close on your application.

UPDATE

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var dialog: Dialog? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {

        if (dialog == null || dialog?.isShowing == false) {

            dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Some title")
                .setMessage("Some message")
                .setPositiveButton("Exit") { dialog, which ->
                    super.onBackPressed()
                }
                .setNeutralButton("Action 1") { dialog, which ->
                    //DO SOME ACTION
                    dialog.cancel()
                }
                .setNegativeButton("Action 2") { dialog, which ->
                    //DO SOME ACTION
                    dialog.cancel()
                }
                .create()

            dialog!!.show()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to add a custom dialog box with custom layout